# How to make a responsive menu with simple jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying a simple responsive menu with Css and jQuery. I want the jQuery script to work only on a certain window width. When I resize the browser. Here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".resmenu").click(function(){
    $(".menu").slideToggle();
   }); 

   $(".submenu").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active_submenu");
    $(this).parent().find(".dropdown").slideToggle();
   }); 

  });
```

```css
.container {
 width:980px;
 margin:100px auto 0 auto;
 font-family:arial;
}

ul, li {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

.resmenu {
 display:none;
}

.menu li {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
}
.menu li a {
 font-size: 14px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #3b2612;
 padding: 6px 17px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li:hover a {
 background: #444;
 color: #fff !important;
}


.menu li ul {
 position: absolute;
 width: 250px;
 z-index: 5;
 left: 0px;
 top:28px;
 display:none;
 
}
.menu li:hover ul {
 display:block;
}
.menu li ul li {
 display: block;
}

.menu li ul li a {
 padding: 6px 17px;
 transition: all 0.2s;
 text-transform: capitalize;
}
.menu li ul li a:hover {
 background: #000;
}


/*--- responsive ----*/
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {

.resmenu {
 color: #fff !important;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none !important;
 background: #6ca2bd;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}
.menu {
 display: none;
 background: #444444;
}
.menu li {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
}
.menu li a {
 color: #fff;
 font-size:14px;
 padding: 6px 17px;
}
.menu li a:hover {
 background-color: #000;
 color: #000;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
.active_submenu {
 background-color: #ceb689 !important;
 color: #fff !important;
}

.menu li ul {
 display: none;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 display:none;
 
}
.menu li:hover ul {
 display: none;
 top: 0px;
}
 
.menu li a.active {
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'opensanssemibold';
}
 
.menu li ul li a {
 background:#333;
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="btm_header">
       <a href="javascript:void();" class="resmenu">Menu</a>
       
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="submenu">Dropdown One  <span></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="submenu">Dropdown Two <span></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown">
     <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
     </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

It is working on 768px screen size, but when I click on the drop-down link instead of hover on more than 768 screen size, the drop down link is slide toggle. I need this script work on certain width only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(window).width()` to get the width of the screen and use it in your condition:

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
         // run your code here
}
```

**See code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".resmenu").click(function() {
    $(".menu").slideToggle();
  });

  $(".submenu").click(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
      $(this).toggleClass("active_submenu");
      $(this).parent().find(".dropdown").slideToggle();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 980px;
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
  font-family: arial;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.resmenu {
  display: none;
}

.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.menu li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #3b2612;
  padding: 6px 17px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li:hover a {
  background: #444;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 5;
  left: 0px;
  top: 28px;
  display: none;
}

.menu li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu li ul li {
  display: block;
}

.menu li ul li a {
  padding: 6px 17px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.menu li ul li a:hover {
  background: #000;
}


/*--- responsive ----*/

@media screen and (min-width:769px) {
  .menu {
    display: block!important;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  .resmenu {
    color: #fff !important;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    background: #6ca2bd;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
    background: #444444;
  }
  .menu li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }
  .menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 6px 17px;
  }
  .menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #000;
    transition: all 0.3s;
  }
  .active_submenu {
    background-color: #ceb689 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
  }
  .menu li ul {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
  }
  .menu li:hover ul {
    display: none;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .menu li a.active {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'opensanssemibold';
  }
  .menu li ul li a {
    background: #333;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="btm_header">
    <a href="#" class="resmenu">Menu</a>

    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="submenu">Dropdown One  <span></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="submenu">Dropdown Two <span></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: after click for toggle responsive menu when i resize the browser to more than 768 resolution, the entire menu is hiding.

Comment: @MahmoodMohammed i fixed the problem...see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In css change "container" width to 100%, and set max-width to 980px.